# Best way to add Chat (Web-Socket) in NextJS 13

Tags: express, sockets, next.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a **NextJS 13** application that's built on top of the `app-router` backend. I'm also using **MongoDB** as my database. I need to implement a real-time chat within my app, there will be multiple chats of a single user working concurrently, so I'll have to initiate seperate web-socket channels for each conversation.

I tried implementing chat using `Socket-IO` as detailed in [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZbX4Ok9YX94&t=30339s&ab_channel=CodeWithAntonio), but the implementation relies on **axios** API calls to send/receive messages, which is not ideal for me.

I understand I'll have to create a seperate server to manage my web-socket server, but I'm not entirely sure what the best approach would be to accomplish that. If there's an easy way to achieve the required functionality without modifying a significant portion of my existing architecture (maybe using an `Express` server), it'd be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a socket.io in a serverless environment can be quite difficult as one would have to maintain sticky session and many other aspects of the sockets as well. To achieve the behaviour you are looking for, you can create a separate Node.JS and Express server as you mentioned in your question. However, an other approach might be using a real-time database to handle such events. MongoDB doesn't have support or realtime database updation hoever, Supabase or Firebase can be used to achieve this functionality.
My verdict will be to create a separate Node.js and Express server.